# Getting a mysqli_conect error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am runing codeingiter on local host and was working fine but after completing my project i moved files on my server now the problem is that I am keep getting an unusual error with codeigniter which I had never been got before I searched on google a lot but the problem is that I am not getting an accurate answer related to my issue

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /home/begazed/public_html/demo/begazed/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 125

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 125

Backtrace:
```

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server does not have php-mysql package installed. You will have to install it and reload the server. Package might be different on the basis of your PHP version. I hope this helped.

Comment: so how do i install on cpanel do i have to contact the hosting ?

Comment: my version is php 5.7

Comment: If you do not have access to Command Line Interface of your server. It is better you call your hosting and get it installed.